# fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'nan.h': No such file or directory [C:\Projects\TK\node_modules\symbology\build\symbology.vcxproj]

Tags: node.js, vue.js, npm, nuxt.js, nuxtjs3

Getting error while running **yarn install**. I tried everything that's on internet but nothing worked. I have successfully installed node and npm. As part of the requirements I am supposed to run: yarn install

1. windows 10 pro 64bit
2. node v16.13.0
3. node-gyp v8.3.0
4. npm 8.1.0

```
    C:\Projects\TK>yarn install
    yarn install v1.22.17
    info No lockfile found.
    warning package-lock.json found. Your project contains lock files generated by tools other than Yarn. It is advised not to mix package managers in order to avoid resolution inconsistencies caused by unsynchronized lock files. To clear this warning, remove package-lock.json.
    [1/4] Resolving packages...
    warning nuxt3 > @nuxt/webpack-builder > webpack-hot-middleware > querystring@0.2.1: The querystring API is considered Legacy. new code should use the URLSearchParams API instead.
    warning nuxt3 > @nuxt/nitro > @vercel/nft > node-pre-gyp@0.13.0: Please upgrade to @mapbox/node-pre-gyp: the non-scoped node-pre-gyp package is deprecated and only the @mapbox scoped package will recieve updates in the future
    [2/4] Fetching packages...
    warning Pattern ["@nuxt/kit@npm:@nuxt/kit-edge@3.0.0-27265876.3cd4494"] is trying to unpack in the same destination "C:\\Users\\VISSRXS2\\AppData\\Local\\Yarn\\Cache\\v6\\npm-@nuxt-kit-3.0.0-27265876.3cd4494-3375d07f032a41ae6b58dc3725fae15ef5a76234-integrity\\node_modules\\@nuxt\\kit" as pattern ["@nuxt/kit@npm:@nuxt/kit-edge@latest"]. This could result in non-deterministic behavior, skipping.
    [3/4] Linking dependencies...
    warning " > symbology@3.0.6" has unmet peer dependency "@mapbox/node-pre-gyp@^1.0.2".
    warning " > @css-render/vue3-ssr@0.15.6" has unmet peer dependency "vue@^3.0.11".
    warning " > naive-ui@2.20.1" has unmet peer dependency "vue@^3.0.0".
    warning "naive-ui > @babel/eslint-parser@7.16.0" has unmet peer dependency "@babel/core@>=7.11.0".
    warning "naive-ui > @babel/eslint-parser@7.16.0" has unmet peer dependency "eslint@^7.5.0 || ^8.0.0".
    warning "naive-ui > vdirs@0.1.4" has unmet peer dependency "vue@^3.0.11".
    warning "naive-ui > vooks@0.2.10" has unmet peer dependency "vue@^3.0.0".
    warning "naive-ui > vueuc@0.4.15" has unmet peer dependency "vue@^3.0.11".
    warning "nuxt-windicss > vite-plugin-windicss@1.4.12" has unmet peer dependency "vite@^2.0.1".
    warning "nuxt3 > @nuxt/vite-builder > autoprefixer@10.4.0" has unmet peer dependency "postcss@^8.1.0".
    warning "nuxt3 > @nuxt/vite-builder > postcss-import@14.0.2" has unmet peer dependency "postcss@^8.0.0".       
    warning "nuxt3 > @nuxt/vite-builder > postcss-url@10.1.3" has unmet peer dependency "postcss@^8.0.0".
    warning "nuxt3 > @nuxt/vite-builder > rollup-plugin-visualizer@5.5.2" has unmet peer dependency "rollup@^2.0.0".
    [4/4] Building fresh packages...
    [7/7] ⡀ @prisma/client
    [2/7] ⡀ bcrypt
    [-/7] ⢀ waiting...
    [4/7] ⢀ symbology
    error C:\Projects\TK\node_modules\symbology: Command failed.
    Exit code: 1
    Command: node ./scripts/install.js && npm run binary:install
    Arguments:
    Directory: C:\Projects\TK\node_modules\symbology
    Output:
    Removing any existing .zint directory...
    Cloning zint at '89518c4' in C:\Projects\TK\node_modules\symbology\.zint
    Successfully cloned. Applying code patches...
    Creating zint config header file...
    Done.
    
    > symbology@3.0.6 binary:install
    > node-pre-gyp install --fallback-to-build
    
    node-pre-gyp info it worked if it ends with ok
    node-pre-gyp info using node-pre-gyp@1.0.6
    node-pre-gyp info using node@16.13.0 | win32 | x64
    node-pre-gyp info check checked for "C:\Projects\TK\node_modules\symbology\bin\binding\bin\symbology.node" (not found)
    node-pre-gyp http GET https://github.com/jshor/symbology/releases/download/3.0.6/symbology_win32_x64_node-v93.tar.gz
    node-pre-gyp ERR! install request to https://github.com/jshor/symbology/releases/download/3.0.6/symbology_win32_x64_node-v93.tar.gz failed, reason: unable to get local issuer certificate
    node-pre-gyp WARN Pre-built binaries not installable for symbology@3.0.6 and node@16.13.0 (node-v93 ABI, unknown) (falling back to source compile with node-gyp)
    node-pre-gyp WARN Hit error request to https://github.com/jshor/symbology/releases/download/3.0.6/symbology_win32_x64_node-v93.tar.gz failed, reason: unable to get local issuer certificate
    gyp info it worked if it ends with ok
    gyp info using node-gyp@8.2.0
    gyp info using node@16.13.0 | win32 | x64
    gyp info ok
    gyp info it worked if it ends with ok
    gyp info using node-gyp@8.2.0
    gyp info using node@16.13.0 | win32 | x64
    gyp info find Python using Python version 3.10.0 found at "C:\Python310\python.exe"
    gyp info find VS using VS2019 (16.11.31729.503) found at:
    gyp info find VS "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools"
    gyp info find VS run with --verbose for detailed information
    gyp info spawn C:\Python310\python.exe
    gyp info spawn args [
    gyp info spawn args   'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\gyp\\gyp_main.py',gyp info spawn args   'binding.gyp',
    gyp info spawn args   '-f',
    gyp info spawn args   'msvs',
    gyp info spawn args   '-I',
    gyp info spawn args   'C:\\Projects\\TK\\node_modules\\symbology\\build\\config.gypi',
    gyp info spawn args   '-I',
    gyp info spawn args   'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\addon.gypi',      
    gyp info spawn args   '-I',
    gyp info spawn args   'C:\\Users\\VISSRXS2\\AppData\\Local\\node-gyp\\Cache\\16.13.0\\include\\node\\common.gypi',
    gyp info spawn args   '-Dlibrary=shared_library',
    gyp info spawn args   '-Dvisibility=default',
    gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_root_dir=C:\\Users\\VISSRXS2\\AppData\\Local\\node-gyp\\Cache\\16.13.0',
    gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_gyp_dir=C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\node_modules\\node-gyp',   
    gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_lib_file=C:\\\\Users\\\\VISSRXS2\\\\AppData\\\\Local\\\\node-gyp\\\\Cache\\\\16.13.0\\\\<(target_arch)\\\\node.lib',
    gyp info spawn args   '-Dmodule_root_dir=C:\\Projects\\TK\\node_modules\\symbology',
    gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_engine=v8',
    gyp info spawn args   '--depth=.',
    gyp info spawn args   '--no-parallel',
    gyp info spawn args   '--generator-output',
    gyp info spawn args   'C:\\Projects\\TK\\node_modules\\symbology\\build',
    gyp info spawn args   '-Goutput_dir=.'
    gyp info spawn args ]
    gyp info ok
    gyp info it worked if it ends with ok
    gyp info using node-gyp@8.2.0
    gyp info using node@16.13.0 | win32 | x64
    gyp info spawn C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\MSBuild\Current\Bin\MSBuild.exe  
    gyp info spawn args [
    gyp info spawn args   'build/binding.sln',
    gyp info spawn args   '/clp:Verbosity=minimal',
    gyp info spawn args   '/nologo',
    gyp info spawn args   '/p:Configuration=Release;Platform=x64'
    gyp info spawn args ]
    Building the projects in this solution one at a time. To enable parallel build, please add the "-m" switch.    
    cl : command line warning D9025: overriding '/W3' with '/w' [C:\Projects\TK\node_modules\symbology\build\symbology.vcxproj]
      output.c
    cl : command line warning D9025: overriding '/W3' with '/w' [C:\Projects\TK\node_modules\symbology\build\symbology.vcxproj]
      2of5.c
    cl : command line warning D9025: overriding '/W3' with '/w' [C:\Projects\TK\node_modules\symbology\build\symbology.vcxproj]
      auspost.c
    cl : command line warning D9025: overriding '/W3' with '/w' [C:\Projects\TK\node_modules\symbology\build\symbology.vcxproj]
      aztec.c
    cl : command line warning D9025: overriding '/W3' with '/w' [C:\Projects\TK\node_modules\symbology\build\symbology.vcxproj]
      code.c
    cl : command line warning D9025: overriding '/W3' with '/w' [C:\Projects\TK\node_modules\symbology\build\symbology.vcxproj]
      code1.c
    cl : command line warning D9025: overriding '/W3' with '/w' [C:\Projects\TK\node_modules\symbology\build\symbology.vcxproj]
      code16k.c
    cl : command line warning D9025: overriding '/W3' with '/w' [C:\Projects\TK\node_modules\symbology\build\symbology.vcxproj]
      code49.c
    cl : command line warning D9025: overriding '/W3' with '/w' [C:\Projects\TK\node_modules\symbology\build\symbology.vcxproj]
      code128.c
    cl : command line warning D9025: overriding '/W3' with '/w' [C:\Projects\TK\node_modules\symbology\build\symbology.vcxproj]
      common.c
    cl : command line warning D9025: overriding '/W3' with '/w' [C:\Projects\TK\node_modules\symbology\build\symbology.vcxproj]
      composite.c
    cl : command line warning D9025: overriding '/W3' with '/w' [C:\Projects\TK\node_modules\symbology\build\symbology.vcxproj]
      dmatrix.c
    cl : command line warning D9025: overriding '/W3' with '/w' [C:\Projects\TK\node_modules\symbology\build\symbology.vcxproj]
      gridmtx.c
    cl : command line warning D9025: overriding '/W3' with '/w' [C:\Projects\TK\node_modules\symbology\build\symbology.vcxproj]
      gs1.c
    cl : command line warning D9025: overriding '/W3' with '/w' [C:\Projects\TK\node_modules\symbology\build\symbology.vcxproj]
      imail.c
    cl : command line warning D9025: overriding '/W3' with '/w' [C:\Projects\TK\node_modules\symbology\build\symbology.vcxproj]
      large.c
    cl : command line warning D9025: overriding '/W3' with '/w' [C:\Projects\TK\node_modules\symbology\build\symbology.vcxproj]
      library.c
    cl : command line warning D9025: overriding '/W3' with '/w' [C:\Projects\TK\node_modules\symbology\build\symbology.vcxproj]
      maxicode.c
    cl : command line warning D9025: overriding '/W3' with '/w' [C:\Projects\TK\node_modules\symbology\build\symbology.vcxproj]
      medical.c
    cl : command line warning D9025: overriding '/W3' with '/w' [C:\Projects\TK\node_modules\symbology\build\symbology.vcxproj]
      pdf417.c
    cl : command line warning D9025: overriding '/W3' with '/w' [C:\Projects\TK\node_modules\symbology\build\symbology.vcxproj]
      plessey.c
    cl : command line warning D9025: overriding '/W3' with '/w' [C:\Projects\TK\node_modules\symbology\build\symbology.vcxproj]
      png.c
    cl : command line warning D9025: overriding '/W3' with '/w' [C:\Projects\TK\node_modules\symbology\build\symbology.vcxproj]
      postal.c
    cl : command line warning D9025: overriding '/W3' with '/w' [C:\Projects\TK\node_modules\symbology\build\symbology.vcxproj]
      ps.c
    cl : command line warning D9025: overriding '/W3' with '/w' [C:\Projects\TK\node_modules\symbology\build\symbology.vcxproj]
      qr.c
    cl : command line warning D9025: overriding '/W3' with '/w' [C:\Projects\TK\node_modules\symbology\build\symbology.vcxproj]
      reedsol.c
    cl : command line warning D9025: overriding '/W3' with '/w' [C:\Projects\TK\node_modules\symbology\build\symbology.vcxproj]
      rss.c
    cl : command line warning D9025: overriding '/W3' with '/w' [C:\Projects\TK\node_modules\symbology\build\symbology.vcxproj]
      svg.c
    cl : command line warning D9025: overriding '/W3' with '/w' [C:\Projects\TK\node_modules\symbology\build\symbology.vcxproj]
      telepen.c
    cl : command line warning D9025: overriding '/W3' with '/w' [C:\Projects\TK\node_modules\symbology\build\symbology.vcxproj]
      upcean.c
    cl : command line warning D9025: overriding '/W3' with '/w' [C:\Projects\TK\node_modules\symbology\build\symbology.vcxproj]
      bmp.c
    cl : command line warning D9025: overriding '/W3' with '/w' [C:\Projects\TK\node_modules\symbology\build\symbology.vcxproj]
      codablock.c
    cl : command line warning D9025: overriding '/W3' with '/w' [C:\Projects\TK\node_modules\symbology\build\symbology.vcxproj]
      dotcode.c
    cl : command line warning D9025: overriding '/W3' with '/w' [C:\Projects\TK\node_modules\symbology\build\symbology.vcxproj]
      eci.c
    cl : command line warning D9025: overriding '/W3' with '/w' [C:\Projects\TK\node_modules\symbology\build\symbology.vcxproj]
      emf.c
    cl : command line warning D9025: overriding '/W3' with '/w' [C:\Projects\TK\node_modules\symbology\build\symbology.vcxproj]
      gb2312.c
    cl : command line warning D9025: overriding '/W3' with '/w' [C:\Projects\TK\node_modules\symbology\build\symbology.vcxproj]
      gb18030.c
    cl : command line warning D9025: overriding '/W3' with '/w' [C:\Projects\TK\node_modules\symbology\build\symbology.vcxproj]
      general_field.c
    cl : command line warning D9025: overriding '/W3' with '/w' [C:\Projects\TK\node_modules\symbology\build\symbology.vcxproj]
      gif.c
    cl : command line warning D9025: overriding '/W3' with '/w' [C:\Projects\TK\node_modules\symbology\build\symbology.vcxproj]
      hanxin.c
    cl : command line warning D9025: overriding '/W3' with '/w' [C:\Projects\TK\node_modules\symbology\build\symbology.vcxproj]
      mailmark.c
    cl : command line warning D9025: overriding '/W3' with '/w' [C:\Projects\TK\node_modules\symbology\build\symbology.vcxproj]
      pcx.c
    cl : command line warning D9025: overriding '/W3' with '/w' [C:\Projects\TK\node_modules\symbology\build\symbology.vcxproj]
      raster.c
    cl : command line warning D9025: overriding '/W3' with '/w' [C:\Projects\TK\node_modules\symbology\build\symbology.vcxproj]
      sjis.c
    cl : command line warning D9025: overriding '/W3' with '/w' [C:\Projects\TK\node_modules\symbology\build\symbology.vcxproj]
      tif.c
    cl : command line warning D9025: overriding '/W3' with '/w' [C:\Projects\TK\node_modules\symbology\build\symbology.vcxproj]
      ultra.c
    cl : command line warning D9025: overriding '/W3' with '/w' [C:\Projects\TK\node_modules\symbology\build\symbology.vcxproj]
      vector.c
    cl : command line warning D9025: overriding '/W3' with '/w' [C:\Projects\TK\node_modules\symbology\build\symbology.vcxproj]
      main.cpp
    C:\Projects\TK\node_modules\symbology\src\binding\main.cpp(10,10): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'nan.h': No such file or directory [C:\Projects\TK\node_modules\symbology\build\symbology.vcxproj]
    gyp ERR! build error
    gyp ERR! stack Error: `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\MSBuild\Current\Bin\MSBuild.exe` failed with exit code: 1
    gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onExit (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\build.js:194:23)
    gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (node:events:390:28)
    gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (node:internal/child_process:290:12)
    gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 10.0.19043
    gyp ERR! command "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js" "build" "--fallback-to-build" "--module=C:\\Projects\\TK\\node_modules\\symbology\\bin\\binding\\bin\\symbology.node" "--module_name=symbology" "--module_path=C:\\Projects\\TK\\node_modules\\symbology\\bin\\binding\\bin" "--napi_version=8" "--node_abi_napi=napi" "--napi_build_version=0" "--node_napi_label=node-v93"
    gyp ERR! cwd C:\Projects\TK\node_modules\symbology
    gyp ERR! node -v v16.13.0
    gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v8.2.0
    gyp ERR! not ok
    node-pre-gyp ERR! build error
    node-pre-gyp ERR! stack Error: Failed to execute 'C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js build --fallback-to-build --module=C:\Projects\TK\node_modules\symbology\bin\binding\bin\symbology.node --module_name=symbology --module_path=C:\Projects\TK\node_modules\symbology\bin\binding\bin --napi_version=8 --node_abi_napi=napi --napi_build_version=0 --node_napi_label=node-v93' (1)
    node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (C:\Projects\TK\node_modules\@mapbox\node-pre-gyp\lib\util\compile.js:89:23)
    node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (node:events:390:28)
    node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at maybeClose (node:internal/child_process:1064:16)
    node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (node:internal/child_process:301:5)
    node-pre-gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 10.0.19043
    node-pre-gyp ERR! command "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Projects\\TK\\node_modules\\@mapbox\\node-pre-gyp\\bin\\node-pre-gyp" "install" "--fallback-to-build"
    node-pre-gyp ERR! cwd C:\Projects\TK\node_modules\symbology
    node-pre-gyp ERR! node -v v16.13.0
    node-pre-gyp ERR! node-pre-gyp -v v1.0.6
    node-pre-gyp ERR! not ok
    Failed to execute 'C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-
```

Comment: Hi, please try fixing some issues. Like the one written on the 4th line.

Comment: Also, please give us more context as of what you're trying to do here, you didn't mentioned [tag:nuxtjs3]. Are you willing to use the v2 or the v3 here?

Comment: If you target v3, did you looked for some "windows" keyword issues here? https://github.com/nuxt/framework/issues?page=4&q=is%3Aissue+windows

Comment: @kissu Yes I am targeting v3 here